# Trouble while Updating Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, apt, ubuntu-server

Situation: I have a Zentyal Server with 3 VM (Qemu) managed with KVM Manager.
 All of them running on Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS
Host: Zentyal 6.0.1
VM1: Ubuntu Server 
VM2: Zentyal 6.0.1
VM3: Ubuntu Server

Problem:
When Update --> Upgrading the Guests can update/upgrade without any further problem.
just apt-get update --> apt-get upgrade. works.

*when i update the Host i get the message

```
Fehl:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Zeitüberschreitung bei Verbindung [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
```

Timeout by the connection

Host und VM2 have the same configuration but VM2 has not the problem when updating/upgrading

here the source.list from Host

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic extras main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic extras main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner

deb http://archive.zentyal.org/zentyal 6.0 main

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
```

Does anyone has an Idea?

thanks!

Comment: APT often has issues behind a proxy.

Comment: Thanks. I removed Squid (Proxy) but still same situation.